Outlook message truncated after first line
We've got an interesting and strange issue.
The company uses mostly Microsoft Office 2019 version, and there's a globally used third-party ERP.
Some employees (according to their position) receiving stock monitoring emails occassionally (a few times a day), sent by this ERP application. So, the e-mails can be: "the stock of the following items are zero" and "the following items are in stock again".
Now, here's the trick: the contents of these emails, the message body are compiled by a complex stored procedure in the database level! (MSSQL 2019)
For some reason (after an Office update in summer of 2024) the message gets truncated right after a first line ("the stock of the following items are zero"...).
First, we thought (wrong) the inserted line breaks and the series of dashes in the stored procedure caused this problem. But the provider put these lines into comment, and it didn't help.
I found a temporary solution by executing the comment below and disabling Office auto-update:
officec2rclient /update user updatetoversion=16.0.13901.20462
Some sites using even older version (Office 2016) and this issue is not present there.
However there's something else needs to be told:

the message is truncated in the Outlook preview pane and even when I open the message in a window.
when I click to reply, reply all, or forward the message body turns into visible and the essential part can be read.
the message in Outlook Web Access is also readable
I configured an email address in the Windows Mail app and it works perfectly (I couldn't set up the mail profile in "New Outlook (PWA)")

The question is: where to look for the solution and of course what could be the solution to this scenario?
Does anybody met any similar issue before?
Thanks for your help in advance!
Regards

Are you describing the situation that this post asks? Try the following to see if it works: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1321199/outlook-client-email-truncation-issue-on-windows

Hi! Yes, exactly!
The same issue described in that topic.
However the recommended steps didn't solve the problem...
